# Looking for a linked word

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

Currently, I have a directed graph representing the words linked to a certain category. Here is a small representation.

[image]

The problem that I am trying to solve is given a word, for example, `cycling`, I need to find the categories(could be one as in a disconnected graph or connected as shown in the picture). Here `cycling` has 2 categories namely `exercise` and `entertainment`

Which traversal algorithm will best suit to solve the problem? In terms of data structure, do we have other alternatives that are more memory and time efficient when looking for the immediate category for a given input word?

Answer (score 1):

Are your nodes labeled? You can add labels in vertices. Label each vertex as `category` and `non-category`.

**Simple Solution**

First you need to find word in graph, then use [DFS](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/) for finding all categories and subcategories.

**Solution 2** *Only if you have one layer of categories*

- Pick random node in graph.
- Find categories of this node
- Look for each category if there exists your word.
- Label all words in this category as used
- Repeat this steps until all nodes are used.